# Add XML element if it doesn't exist

Tags: c#, xml

I am adding a new checkbox to my frogram and need to save it's value to the setting file.
I am trying to do it with the following code:

```
private void CloseDisconnectedCbx_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(BotsFile);
    var savedBots = doc.Descendants("SavedBots")
        .Where(p => p.Element("BotName").Value.ToLower()
                    == SelectBotBox.SelectedItem.ToString().ToLower())
        .Elements("CloseDisconnected").FirstOrDefault();
    if (savedBots == null)
    {
        try
        {
            doc.Descendants("SavedBots")
               .Where(p => p.Element("BotName").Value.ToLower()
                           == SelectBotBox.SelectedItem.ToString().ToLower())
               .FirstOrDefault()
               .Add(new XElement("CloseDisconnected",
                    Convert.ToInt32(CloseDisconnectedCbx.Checked)));
            doc.Save(BotsFile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

It does add the new element, however, it looks like this:

```
<CloseDisconnected/> VALUE
```

It never ends the closing of the element.
Is my code wrong, or have I just forgotten something?

This code is only supposed to be triggered if the element is not found in the XML file.
If it is, the change will be handeled by another button.

Comment: show the code that adds closedisconnected please

Comment: really hard to read those oneliners, I think would help readability a low if it was split to several lines (like extracted search value to separate variable, element to add, etc.).

Comment: @HatSoft The code for adding the CloseDisconnected is within the Try clause.

Comment: @Rickard dang yes your right sorry about that

Comment: @Giedrius Sorry for the oneliner. I don't always break them up. Regarding the FirstOrDefault(), Yes, it does return the Node that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Check parenthesis in your code

XElement xElem = new XElement("root");
xElem.Add( new XElement("CloseDisconnected", "123") ); // generates what you expect
xElem.Add( new XElement("CloseDisconnected"), "123"); // generates what you see
```

Comment: So those oneliners did their evil job :)